# OpenCV Convert Image to Bytes and Back

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to convert images to a vector of bytes and back again but each image is horrible distorted. I was hoping someone could tell me why.

I have this as my conversion methods.

```
typedef unsigned char byte;

std::vector<byte> matToBytes(cv::Mat image)
{
    int size = image.total() * image.elemSize();
    std::vector<byte> img_bytes(size);
    img_bytes.assign(image.datastart, image.dataend);
    return img_bytes;
}

cv::Mat bytesToMat(vector<byte> bytes,int width,int height)
{
    cv::Mat image(height,width,CV_8UC3,bytes.data());  
    return image;
}
```

It works but not well, I hope someone can spot why. I am pretty lost!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was playing around with my code and I got this to work.

```
cv::Mat bytesToMat(vector<byte> bytes,int width,int height)
{
    cv::Mat image = cv::Mat(height,width,CV_8UC3,bytes.data()).clone(); // make a copy
    return image;
}
```

I suppose the `.clone()` does something importat

Comment: when `bytes` goes out of scope, without `clone` the image is pointing to trash values, so you need `clone` to make a deep copy